# Accessing an R package not in library

Tags: r

I am very new to R and struggling to load a package. This package can only be downloaded as a development version from Github using DevTools and I do not have the administrative privileges to do so. Currently, it is downloaded in a software folder separate from the normal R library with the path /local/software. I have tried to load the library using the following lines:

```
>.libPaths(c("/usr/local/packages/r-4.0.3/lib64/R/library", "/local/software")) 
>library(package, lib.loc="/local/software")
```

However, when I run I get the error: Error in library(package): ‘package’ is not a valid installed package Execution halted

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and would appreciate any advice anyone could offer! Let me know if any additional information would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it slightly differently -- R is pretty strict about using a library *but the nice part is you can use your own path* as e.g. your `/local/software`.

Start with `.libPaths()` as you *but only add the preferred directory you can write to*:  `.libPaths("/local/software")`.

Now run the installation command, for example `remotes::install_github("somerepo/somepackage")`. It *will by default write to first entry in `.libPaths()`* -- the one you just gave.

Now you should be able to load it: `library(somepackage)`.